# Why is my palm tree dying?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care, palm

Why is my palm tree dying?

I have used a special [palm tree fertilizer](https://www.miraclegro.com/smg/goprod/shake-n-feed-palm-plant-food/prod11850032?locale=en_US) and it didn't help it at all. The tree was already looking like this just not as bad before I used the fertilizer. I actually didn't use much just sprinkled some around the bottom of the tree. This is in Mobile, AL

How can I save it?

[image]

---

The tree was already looking like this just not as bad before I used the fertilizer. I actually didn't use much just sprinkled some around the bottom of the tree. Is it too late for this tree? Is it savable?

Comment: Welcome to the group Amanda!  Can you share some more details on the type of palm tree, your location, the fertilizer you used, how long you had the palm tree etc so someone can answer your question.  A picture of the dying palm tree would help as well

Comment: I uploaded a pic of the tree when I submitted the post but it didn't show up. I used shake n feed fertilizer. The palm tree was already planted in the yard when we moved in the house about a year ago so I am not sure. The tree is located in Mobile, AL.

Comment: I am not even sure what kind of palm tree this is?

Comment: Did it get really cold before this happened? Palms don't like the cold.

Comment: We get cold weather I don't think this past winter was cold enough to kill this tree though.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not overlook possibility of pests or disease, such as the red palm weevil.  The fertilizer added to the problem.

Check your local phonebook for a place to have plants tested by a professional.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Wind Palm, I think.  How much did you use to fertilize?  Is this the first time you have fertilized this plant?  My initial reaction is too much fertilizer.  What did this look like before you fertilized?  To get to this size it must have been doing great...until you fertilized?  Why did you chose a special palm fertilizer?  What did it look like when you went out to purchase this fertilizer?  What is the formulation of this fertilizer?  Is this next to your lawn?  How do you fertilize your lawn; drop spreader or cast spreader?  The combination of lawn fertilizer and palm fertilizer might have been too much and just a little too much fertilizer is a death sentence.

Comment: Defiantly not Windmill palm, some variety of fan palm, maybe Mexican or California Fan Palm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13910)

Comment: @Alina  I gave the type of palm and the problem was over fertilization.  That was what they asked for.  I asked questions because to give an answer based on a picture and a paragraph without asking for more information would be irresponsible.  Like taking a shot in the dark but trying to help them and get a discussion going.  Gees.

Comment: @DebbieM.  Please explain why Mexican versus Wind or Windmill palm...hate these common names.  I've grown Mexican worked at a nursery that even they didn't know how to tell apart.  Wind, Windmill, Mexican...are all fan palms.  How do you tell the difference between Wind, Windmill, Mexican or Californian?

Comment: @stormy As the OP mentions, "The tree was already looking like this just not as bad before I used the fertilizer. I actually didn't use much just sprinkled some around the bottom of the tree." You asked 8 (eight) questions in an answer, instead of leaving a comment. I do leave comments when I ask something. If I follow the rules, I expect reciprocity. I will flag every user that doesn't follow the rules that I struggle to follow, no matter to whom the answers belong. Just wanted you to know.

Comment: My goodness.  You counted my questions?  Go ahead and flag me sweetie.  I must deserve it!  You do know that I've gotten in trouble for answering questions within comments, yes?  So, I try to do the right thing whatever that is.  I thought it was to help the OP.  Grins.  Gosh, I must be awful!

Comment: ...Washingtonia?